# the command argument is not passed to /bin/sh in popen

Tags: c++, unix, relative-path, popen

Here is a scenario where I use popen as

```
FILE* stream = popen("Root", "r");
```

As per my understanding the Root argument will be passed to /bin/sh and interpretion is done.
In my case, Root should be interpreted as a relative path /user/bin and should be sent back.
Now my problem is I am getting an error saying that this path "/user/bin" does not exist.
Can anyone please tel me what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you have mentioned,  `/user/bin/` does not exist, The file
path will be `/usr/bin`. If the Root is character  array you don't need to give the double quotes.

Comment: thanks for the reply.Actually its my typing mistake its /usr/bin.

Comment: @user3913114 Have you checked that path is available in you system?

Comment: ya i have checked. Its available